# Fundamental differences between a List<Action> vs Action

Tags: c#, delegates

Is there any fundamental difference between to using an action and a list of actions? Seeing that action is a delegate and therefore is a list itself.  For instance:

```
List<Action> technicallyRedundant = new List<Action>();
technicallyRedundant.Add(() => { Console.WriteLine("Action 1"); });
technicallyRedundant.Add(() => { Console.WriteLine("Action 2"); });
```

Is this architecture more readable? Which would be recommended for use when exposing for an external library?

```
Action act = null;
act += () => { Console.WriteLine("Action 1"); }
act += () => { Console.WriteLine("Action 2"); }
```

Comment: What’s the context? A list is more explicit and can help with readability. And multicast delegates have specific behaviors (especially around exception handling) which are occasionally not wanted.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper?"  You can't enumerate the subscribers of an event from outside of the class contained in the event. Doesn't that pretty much disqualify its use as a List?

Comment: @RobertHarvey actions have a function GetInvocationList so you can enumerate them.  Also this is an action not an event

Comment: @Telastyn your right that makes sense I guess it depends on the context of the situation.

Comment: @johnny5: You're responding to a comment that I didn't make.  Read the comment again.  In addition, an event is just a delegate with a specific method signature, so you're making a distinction that doesn't matter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I’m confused to as why you are bringing events into this?  Are you trying to say that events could use an action as method signature, and then you wouldn’t not have access to the invocation list?

Comment: @johnny5: No, I'm saying that there's no material difference.  Look at the code in the OP's example above.  Anywhere you see a +=, you're looking at a *delegate.*  You even said it yourself: there's a `GetInvocationList()` method.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks that makes sense, I thought you were saying there is a difference, because of the comment “Doesn’t that pretty much disqualify it’s use as a list”.

Comment: Both seem problematic, particularly since lists are mutable. Can you describe the use case for your library?

Comment: @EricLippert I have a rest service that allows you to plug into other optional services such as signalr hubs.  I provide an event on the rest service but I’m abstracting the logic for the factory from the configuration file.  Currently I provide a list of Action<IServiceProvider, RestService<TDTO>>, so they can request what services they want from the service provider and manually register them

Comment: @EricLippert if you have time, it would be a blessing to hear your input on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a fundamental difference between the two: type safety.

Whilst `GetInvocationList` can indeed be called on `act` in your example, it doesn't return a list, it returns an array of `Delegate`. As a result, the slower `DynamicInvoke` must be used to run it and the wrong parameters can easily be passed to it, as demonstrated by the following compilable code:

```
Action act = null;
act += () => { Console.WriteLine("Action 1"); };
act += () => { Console.WriteLine("Action 2"); };
foreach (var action in act.GetInvocationList())
{
    action.DynamicInvoke("1");
}
```

Run this and it'll throw a `TargetParameterCountException`.

Whereas with `List<Action>`, we have a strongly typed list. In any iteration of it, we'd be dealing with `Action`, rather than `Delegate`. Thus `Invoke()` can be used, which knows the parameter requirements.

Comment: can’t you cast the delegate back to action and call a regular invoke?

Comment: @johnny5: I don't see how that would help you with anonymous delegates.  You'd have to cast it to an `Action<T>` for some concrete type.

Comment: @johnny5: Have a look here: http://faithlife.codes/blog/2008/07/casting_delegates/

Comment: @RobertHarvey interesting but doesn’t that mean in order to subscribe to the action in the first place you would have to be of type action? So wouldn’t it be safe to assume that all multicast delegates are actually the same type in the invocation list as the declaring, as outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27763068/1938988)

Comment: @johnny5, sure you can cast it back. But that requires you know the type (obvious here, less so in real-world scenarios) and really, why why assign to an array of `Delegate` and then have to cast back again, when `List<Action>` can be used to maintain the correct type directly?

Comment: @DavidArno I agree using the list will almost always be more readable and safer.  I was just trying to fully understand the behaviors of both.  Still a bit confused on when there would be a senario that you wouldn’t know the type of action in the real world, if you change that to be a List wouldn’t you still have the same issues?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is internal. Delegate is a linked list; List uses an array internally. For a public API, you should not use either. List is not supposed to be exposed in properties, and a public delegate is usually an event. Perhaps you want a delegate parameter instead.

As the other poster said, List is strongly typed, but an event can also be strongly typed. The delegate would then be hidden in generated code.

Check out the .net [Framework Design Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/) for public collection property and event/delegate guidelines.